# How to fix credential issue?

Tags: powershell, web-services, authentication

I tried both default credential and user/pass but keep getting 401 unauthorized error. What's the fix?

Here is the error I am getting ....

```
New-WebServiceProxy : The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.
At C:\Scripts\GetItemID_UsingWebServices.ps1:1 char:26
+ $WS = New-WebServiceProxy <<<<  -uri http://server/sites/promo/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (http://server...n/SiteData.asmx:Uri) [New-WebServiceProxy], WebExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebServiceProxy
Property 'Credentials' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Scripts\GetItemID_UsingWebServices.ps1:2 char:5
+ $WS. <<<< Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Credentials:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\GetItemID_UsingWebServices.ps1:12 char:26
+ $GUS = $WS.GetURLSegments <<<< ($ItemURL, $webID, $bucketID, $strListID, $strItemID)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetURLSegments:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Code:

```
$WS = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://server/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx
$WS.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials
#$WS.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::("user", (ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -force), "domain")
$ItemURL = "http://server/sites/promo/sales/testLib/TestFile.txt"
$GUS = $WS.GetURLSegments($ItemURL, $webID, $bID, $strListID, $strItemID)
Write-Host $strItemID
```

---

Update with new code!

This code is working (meaning at least no more 401 error). However, I am still working on it since it does not return any values for webid or bid or listid or itemid.

```
$webID = $null
$bID = $null
$strListID = $null
$strItemID = $null
$GUS
$uri = "http://Server/sites/Promo/TestDocLibrary44/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx"
$WS = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential
$ItemURL = "http://Server/sites/Promot/TestDocLibrary44/2011102100006b.pdf"
$GUS = $WS.GetURLSegments($ItemURL, [REF]$webID,  [REF]$bID,  [REF]$strListID,  [REF]$strItemID)
write-Host $strItemID.value # returning null or blank
write-Host $webID # returning null or blank
Write-Host "Test "
```

Comment: Where are all the SP Gurus ??????

Comment: I went ahead and edited your question to include the information you gave in an answer below. You might also consider asking a new question since we have solved your 401 Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 5):

I don't really know powershell but I know webservices... and I think you need to use `DefaultNetworkCredentials` instead of `DefaultCredentials`:

```
$WS = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://server/sites/promo/sales/_vti_bin/SiteData.asmx
$WS.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$ItemURL = "http://server/sites/promo/sales/testLib/TestFile.txt"
$GUS = $WS.GetURLSegments($ItemURL, $webID, $bID, $strListID, $strItemID)
Write-Host $strItemID
```

Also, make sure the account you are running this script as has access to the SharePoint site. Some webservices require higher permissions levels as well.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and still 401 error...

Comment: Have you double checked the account's permissions?

Comment: Yes, I am running this on WFE with SPAdmin who has full access to the site collection.

Comment: I just noticed that your web service proxy URL was pointing to the root site. I'm guessing `http://server/sites/promo/sales/` is the site which has your doclib in it. Try the updated code.

Comment: Yes sir. I have tried that combination as well.
I tried $WS = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $uri -UseDefaultCredential then I get following error and dont receive 401 error. 
Argument: '2' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
At line:5 char:26
+ $GUS = $WS.GetURLSegments <<<< ($ItemURL,  $webID,  $bID,  $strListID,  $strItemID)

Comment: Ok progress! Can you edit your new code and error into your question (easier to read)? Sounds like you need to change `$webID` to be `[ref]$webID`.

Comment: Yes sir. Now it's working. I mean at least no more 401 error. LOL. However, it should return $strItemID but it does not. Hmm. any idea. write-Host $strItemID OR write-Host $strItemID.value , none of them worked. returns blank or null for everything. (webid,listid,itemid,)

Comment: Write-Host $GUS returns false... hmm, meaning what ...

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to specify the password, I believe it has to be a secure string:

```
$WS.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::("USERNAME", (ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -force))
```

If you're specifying a domain, I believe it needs to be as a parameter, not as a fully qualified username:

```
$WS.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::("USERNAME", (ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSWORD" -AsPlainText -force), "DOMAIN")
```

See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx

Comment: I updated the original post. I am still getting the same 401 unauthorized error. Is there something I need to check in IIS? From browser I can see all the methods for the _vti_bin/sitedata.asmx. I am logged in spadmin on the SP WFE.

Comment: What are you trying to do would be a good place to start I guess... there's no a lot to go on here.

Comment: I am trying to get doc id for an item using GetURLSegments method via web services with Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

Include domain if necessary

```
$username = "username"  
$password = "password"

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

#assign $cred to the webServicesProxy.Credentials
$webServicesProxy.Credentials = $cred
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I found to this problem is to use -UseDefaultCredential, but run the script with the "run as" option. And in the run as command you specify the credentials you need to hardcode.